# How can I position a scrollable bar at the bottom of a page regardless of screen size?

Tags: css

I was looking at some landing pages for inspiration, and came across this one: http://do.thelandingpagecourse.com/

Note how it has a dark grey bar at the bottom of the page, which lines up exactly at the bottom of the page.  How can I have this bar line up at the bottom if I don't know the screen size?  Can you show it in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the work:

```
#footer { position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; width:100%; /* etc etc.. */ }
```

Just make sure you also set `padding-bottom` to *body* with the same value as the height of the footer, so that content won't be hidden underneath the footer.

Comment: I want the element to scroll with the page, not be a sticky at the bottom.

Comment: @mindandsky ok, I updated the answer. Test the new code.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bottomBar
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%
}
```